Confusion of phase spectrum definition of Fourier transform
As we know, the Fourier transform is generally in complex form say,
$$X(\omega) = A + jB$$
The magnitude spectrum is without disputing
$$|X(\omega)| = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$
But, how about the definition of phase spectrum (in the community of signal analysis)
$$\angle X(\omega) =\tan^{-1}\frac{B}{A}\;?$$
Do I have to discuss the signs of $A$ and $B$?
